# I cannot get a database to display with kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

So i am trying to create a kivy app that gets animal information from a database. It appears to me that my python is not passing variable information to my kivy or something. When I run it I get the error message: line 166, in on_enter
self.n.str = get_name_by_name(self.current)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute` 'str'

My python:

```
# Here are my imports and such
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import sqlite3

# Connecting to my database ---------------------------

conn = sqlite3.connect('animals.db')

c = conn.cursor()


# The class that works with the database
class Ani:

    def __init__(self, name, cass, desc, dang, pic, cons):
        # Name is name
        self.name = name
        # cass refers to an animals class, such as reptile
        self.cass = cass
        # Animal physical description
        self.desc = desc
        # danger refers to what dangers the animal may pose.
        # EX: poisonous, seek medical attention if bitten
        self.dang = dang
        # This will be the animals pic, when this file was created
        # I was not whether to embed the pic or its file path
        self.pic = pic
        # cons is the animals conservation status
        self.cons = cons

    # This
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Ani('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}')".format(self.name, self.cass, self.desc, self.dang, self.pic,
                                                                self.cons)

    # starting functions that work with the database
    # The function to get the animal by name
    def get_ani_by_name(self):
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM animals WHERE name=:name",
                  {'name': self})
        return c.fetchall()

    # Function to get all the animals
    @staticmethod
    def get_all():
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM animals")
        return c.fetchall()

    # Function that gets the animals info by name without the picture. Used as a test
    def get_ani_info(name):
        c.execute("SELECT name, cass, desc, dang, cons FROM animals WHERE name = :name",
                  {'name': name})
        return c.fetchall()


def get_name_by_name(name):
    c.execute("SELECT name FROM animals WHERE name=:name",
              {'name': name})
    return c.fetchall()


def get_cass_by_name(name):
    c.execute("SELECT cass FROM animals WHERE name = :name",
              {'name': name})
    return c.fetchall()


def get_desc_by_name(name):
    c.execute("SELECT desc FROM animals WHERE name = :name",
              {'name': name})
    return c.fetchall()


def get_dang_by_name(name):
    c.execute("SELECT dang FROM animals WHERE name = :name",
              {'name': name})
    return c.fetchall()


def get_cons_by_name(name):
    c.execute("SELECT cons FROM animals WHERE name = :name",
              {'name': name})
    return c.fetchall()


def get_pic_by_name(name):
    c.execute("SELECT pic FROM animals WHERE name = :name",
              {'name': name})
    return c.fetchall()


# The function to get the animal by name
def get_ani_by_name(name):
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM animals WHERE name=:name",
              {'name': name})
    return c.fetchall()


# Function to get all the animals
def get_all():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM animals")
    return c.fetchall()


# Function that gets the animals info by name without the picture. Used as a test
def get_ani_info(name):
    c.execute("SELECT name, cass, desc, dang, cons FROM animals WHERE name = :name",
              {'name': name})
    return c.fetchall()


# Starting my Kivy classes ---------------------------------
# My Main Page Class
class MainPage(Screen):
    search = ObjectProperty()

    def search_btn(self):
        if Ani.get_ani_info(self.search.text):
            AnimalPage.current = self.search.text
            self.reset()
            sm.current = "animal"
        else:
            invalid_search()
            self.reset()
            sm.current = "main"

    def reset(self):
        self.search.text = ""


# The class for my results
class SearchResults(Screen):
    search = ObjectProperty("")
    current = ""


# This class will display the animals information


class AnimalPage(Screen):
    current = ""
    # Animal Name
    n = ObjectProperty("")
    # Animal Class
    cass = ObjectProperty("")
    # Animal Conservation Status
    cons = ObjectProperty("")
    #  Animal Description
    desc = ObjectProperty("")
    # Animal Danger
    dang = ObjectProperty("")
    # Animal Pic
    pic = ObjectProperty("")

    def build(self):
        label = Label(text=get_name_by_name(self.current))
        return label

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        # n, cass, desc, dang, pic, cons = get_ani_by_name(self.current)
        self.n.text = get_name_by_name(self.current)
        self.cass.str = get_cass_by_name(self.current)
        self.desc.str = get_desc_by_name(self.current)
        self.dang.str = get_dang_by_name(self.current)
        self.pic.image = get_pic_by_name(self.current)
        self.cons.str = get_cons_by_name(self.current)

    def back_to_main(self):
        sm.current = "main"


# This class is the screen manager
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

    search = ObjectProperty("")


def invalid_search():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid Search',
                content=Label(text='That is not an animal in the compendium\n'
                                   'check your spelling or search for another\n'
                                   'animal please'),
                size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop.open()


# Loading my kv file

kv = Builder.load_file("animalcomp.kv")
# building another window manager
sm = WindowManager()

# listing my screens. This should enable me to switch via the python document in addition to my kv file.

screens = [MainPage(name="main"), SearchResults(name="results"), AnimalPage(name="animal")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

# This will reset the window

sm.current = "main"


# The App class

class AnimalCompApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    AnimalCompApp().run()
```

And here is my .kv file

```
WindowManager:
    MainPage:
    SearchResults:
    AnimalPage:


<Button>:
    font_size:50
    background_color: 0.333,0.419,0.184,0.5
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.5

<MainPage>:
    name: "main"

    search: search

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text: "Welcome to the \nGeorgia Animal Compendium!"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "top":0.9}
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.15
            halign: "center"

        Label:
            text: "What animal would you \nlike to learn more about: "
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.35, "top": 0.7}
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.15
            halign: "center"

        TextInput:
            id: search
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "top": 0.5}
            multiline: False
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.15

        Button:
            text: "Search"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "y":0.1}
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
            background_color: 0.333,0.419,0.184,0.5
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.search_btn()

<SearchResults>:
    name: "results"

    search: search

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            id: search
            text: "You searched for: "
            pos_hint: {"x":.3, "top":.9}
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.15

        Label:
            text: "This is to fill in where the results will appear and \nthe user may select the appropriate animal, most likely by picture."
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "top": 0.7}
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.15

        Button:
            text: "Back"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "top": 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

        Button:
            text: "To \nAnimal"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.6, "top": 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "animal"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

<AnimalPage>:
    name: "animal"
    n: str(root.n)
    cass: str(root.cass)
    cons: str(root.cons)
    desc: str(root.desc)
    dang: str(root.dang)
    pic: pic

    FloatLayout:

        Image:
            id: pic
            source:
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.0, "top": 1}
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.45
            allow_stretch: True


        Label:
            id: n
            text: str(root.n)
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.7, "y": .8}
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 15**4
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.15
            bold: True

        Label:
            id: cass
            text: str(root.cass)
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.7, "y": .75}
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 15**4
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.15

        Label:
            id: cons
            text: "Conservation Status: " + str(cons)
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.7, "y": .7}
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 15**4
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.15

        Label:
            id: desc
            text: str(root.desc)
            text_size: self.width, None
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "top": 0.6}
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        Label:
            id: dang
            text: str(root.dang)
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "top": .7}
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.15


        Button:
            text: "Previous \nResults"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.0, "top": .3}
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "results"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"


        Button:
            text: "Main Page"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.6, "top": .3}
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
```

if anyone can provide help it would be appreciated.

Comment: Just use the full name of things. No one knows what `Ani` is, but everyone know what an `Animal` is. You saved only 3 letters. The same with every attribute such as `dang`. Just write out `danger`. Some of these aren't just hard to understand, but actually misleading. `cons` actual means something! Having an attribute named `conservation_status` might be long, but it's clear and understandable. In fact, 90% of your comments would disappear with better variable names! Comments are bad as they often get dated and misleading (or flat out wrong) when the program changes, which leads to confusion.

Comment: Not saying that you shouldn't use comments. Comments are useful, but only when you can't explain intent directly with code.

Comment: I realize that it is not easy to read, and had already decided to go back and clean most of my program up. Even so, it is working, up to a certain point. My question was not about the formatting in general. It was about the section I have not been able to get to function. The comments are there because I am still new to Python and having them helps me think.

Comment: Yes, I know, it was just some tips. I've seen people often get confused by their naming after a while. Trying to get it consistent in the beginning is usually a big help for them. It also helps when people are reading your code. I had quite difficulties understanding the code as I always had to go back and check what `c`, `sm`, `kv`, or `self.n` was.

Answer (score 0):

`self.n` is set by `n: str(root.n)` in your kv. I didn't check hard but it looks like you don't set it elsewhere, so it probably ends up as `str(None)`.

When you later run `self.n.str = get_name_by_name(self.current)` you naturally get the error that you've posted: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute` 'str'`

I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do, do you just mean `self.n` instead of `self.n.text`?

Comment: I have tried a few things to get it to work so I just went back and did some reformatting. what I want is for the search from the main page to get the information from the database and display it using the label.

Comment: How would you change it so that it fixed that error I posted?